# ¿Como convertir un docx de un diccionario en word en un vector de palabras a definir y otro con las definiciones de esas palabras?

Tags: python, diccionarios, procesamiento-de-texto, docx, python-docx

Tengo un diccionario en word, en docx, que he ordenado de modo que es texto continuo, con palabras en negrita a definir seguidas de la definición sin negrita.

A modo de ejemplo sería algo así:
**casa** edificio que se usa para vivir
**edificio** lugar construido con ladrillos
**ladrillo** unidad material empleada para hacer edificios

Necesito crear, por así decirlo, una "Matriz" de n filas (= número de palabras a definir) por dos columnas, la primera con las palabras y la segunda con las definiciones.

La forma que estoy probando es corriendo el código, y haciendo que almacene un "diccionario" de modo que debería quedar así: {casa: edificio que se usa para vivir, edificio: construcción para ser habitada, ladrillo: masa de arcilla}

Sin embargo, no se por qué, las definiciones no salen completas. Haciendo este ejemplo de tres definiciones me queda así:
{'casa': 'edificio que se usa para vivir', 'edificio': 's', 'ladrillo': ' unidad material empleada para hacer edificios'}

Como veis la definición de edificio sale mal. Si ahora cojo un diccionario completo, esto ocurre con muchísima frecuencia sin motivo aparente, y casi todas las definiciones salen mal...

No entiendo por qué ocurre. El código empleado es este.

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document('test.docx')

defs = {}
palabra = None
aux = []

for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        if run.bold:
            if palabra is not None:
                defs[palabra] = "".join(aux)
            palabra = run.text
            aux.clear()
        else:
            aux.append(run.text)

if palabra is not None:
    defs[palabra] = "".join(aux)
```

Si alguien entiende de DOCX, y de tratamiento de diccionarios y estos temas, me encantaría poder contactar con él, ya que no encuentro mucha información sobre esto.

A ver si entre todos podemos sacar ésto. Muchas gracias!!! (Es para un Trabajo de Fin de Máster).

Saludos.

Comment: Se me ocurre que tengas marcas de negrita ocultas entre el texto. Por ejemplo tienes "edificio" en negrita, y luego por ejemplo la palabra "construcción", pero tras la primera "c" hay una marca de negrita, algo como si en HTML fuese `"c<b></b>onstrucción"`. Entonces tendrás una palabra vacía negrita, que da por terminada esa definción según tu lógica. Puedes probar a poner un `if run.text` para verificar que efectivamente hay algo en negrita. También puede ayudar que proporciones un docx de ejemplo para hacer pruebas (puedes compartir un enlace a un drive en la nube, por ejemplo)

Comment: Justo eso hice. Cree un docx con esas 3 definiciones, escritas a mano, y sigue dando ese error... No se si se te ocurre otra forma de hacerlo. Seguro que hay una manera muy sencilla. Gracias!!

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el docx con que has probado para que yo también pueda hacer pruebas y diagnosticar el problema?

Comment: Aquí lo tienes! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LErDc5pChygZ_sooPq9c5jwlvC4vczpc/view?usp=sharing         La idea de todo esto, es terminar generando una matriz con las palabras a definir y las definiciones al lado. Quizás la forma que estoy intentando no sea la óptima.

Comment: prueba ahora! perdona

Comment: Pues a mi tu ejemplo me funciona, salvo por que en las definiciones aparecen espacios que podrían ser eliminados con `strip()`. Pero no me ocurre lo de la "s" suelta...Eso sí, he detectado que dentro del word la palabra "ladrillos" aparece misteriosamente separada en dos objetos `run`, uno con "ladrillo" y otro con "s", pero ya que todo se concatena al final sale bien... ¿Seguro que a ti este ejemplo te falla? Por otro lado ¿tienes posibilidad de pedir que el docx tenga otro formato? Lo más sencillo sería usar un separador entre palabra y definición y exportar el docx como texto plano

Comment: Me ocurre el "fallo" con la s. En este ejemplo es el único fallo. Pero con más definiciones, los fallos de este tipo se multiplican. No se a que te refieres con cambiar el formato del docx. Ahora mismo lo que tengo es un diccionario de 500 páginas en docx, pero lo puedo editar y transformar como me haga falta. Por eso no hay problema. Una vez salga el ejemplo pequeño hacerlo para 500 páginas no debería ser un inconveniente. Lo que no estoy muy puesto en como funciona python con DOCX, nunca lo he usado.  ¿Se te ocurre por donde tirar?

Comment: Mejor seguimos en un chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110619/docx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tras conversación en el chat, parece que el problema estaba en que el código que estaba ejecutando no era idéntico al mostrado en su pregunta (pues éste no daba problemas con el documento de ejemplo proporcionado).

El problema era que en un punto del código hacía `aux = run.text` en lugar de `aux.append(run.text)` y el documento word por alguna razón presentaba palabras "rotas" entre varios objetos `run`. Por ejemplo, la palabra "ladrillos" aparecía en dos objetos `run` separados. Uno contenía "ladrillo" y el otro contenía la "s". Mientras estos textos se vayan agregando a una lista `aux` y concatenando todos al final, no habría problema, pero al hacer en cambio `aux = run.text` se sobreescribiría el run anterior con el nuevo, y al final sólo quedaría el último.

### Creación de tabla

Aprovechando ya la respuesta propongo otro enfoque para ayudar a la creación de la tabla final. Ya que no se necesita acceder a las palabras como claves de un `dict`, no es necesario usar esta estructura para guardar las definiciones. Se puede usar en su lugar una lista de tuplas (palabra, definicion) para así preservar el orden incluso en versiones de Python anteriores a 3.6

Este sería un ejemplo de código que construye la lista de definiciones (he incluído de paso algunos `strip()` para eliminar espacios al inicio o final de las definiciones)

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document('ejemplo.docx')

defs = []
palabra = None
aux = []

for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    print("Paragraph")
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        print(f"Run: {run.text!r}")
        if run.bold:
            if palabra:
                definicion = "".join(aux).strip()
                defs.append((palabra, definicion))
            palabra = run.text
            aux=[]
        else:
            aux.append(run.text)

if palabra:
    definicion = "".join(aux).strip()
    defs.append((palabra, definicion))
```

Usando el pequeño documento de ejemplo proporcionado en un enlace en un comentario, el resultado en este caso es:

```
[('casa', 'edificio que se usa para vivir'),
 ('edificio', 'lugar construido con ladrillos'),
 ('ladrillo', 'unidad material empleada para hacer edificios')]
```

Usando pandas se puede cargar esta información en un dataframe para generar con él una tabla:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(defs, columns=["palabra", "definicion"]).set_index("palabra")
```

En un Jupyter Notebook este dataframe se mostraría así:

[image: resultado]

Pero pandas también permite guardarlo en formato LaTeX, o HTML, o CSV... Por ejemplo, el siguiente código:

```
print(df.to_html())
```

produce el HTML del siguiente snippet (que puedes ejecutar para ver la tabla):

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>definicion</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>palabra</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>casa</th>
      <td>edificio que se usa para vivir</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>edificio</th>
      <td>lugar construido con ladrillos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>ladrillo</th>
      <td>unidad material empleada para hacer edificios</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```